# how to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'customers' of null

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm getting error in this code, I'm trying to do an event where in when the page is load, it will do the event. But the problem is when I go to other function, but same page, it gets a error of null on that variable. It has no problem when I execute this codes, but when I'm on other part of my codes this error occurs.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'customers' of null

```
export default class Viewcustomer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.State = {
            customers: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {   /* lifecycle method*/
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/customers/view`)
            .then(res => {
                const customers = res.data;
                this.setState({ customers });
            });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.customers.map(person =>
                    <li>{person.name} {person.Id}{person.fax}{person.NIC}
                        {person.email}{person.website}</li>
                )}
            </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the constructor, `this.State` is supposed to be `this.state`.

Comment: It's also good to show that something is loading when you first load the page and customers is not yet populated. Inside your render you can check if customers.length === 0 and return a "Loading.." or a component of your choice!

Answer (score 0):

Your name of state in render different with in constructor. So, property "customer" can not read in state, because property "customer" available in this.State.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        customers:[]
    }
}


componentDidMount() {   /* lifecycle method*/
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/customers/view`)
      .then(res => {
        const customers = res.data;
        this.setState({customers});
      })
  }

render(){

    return(
        <div>
            { this.state.customers.map(person => 
            <li>{person.name} {person.Id}{person.fax}{person.NIC}
            {person.email}{person.website}</li>
            )}
        </div>
```

You can use this.State if you don't want to use setState.